# How to avoid inline toolbar auto hide in tinymce?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I need to anchor the toolbar at the bottom of the editor, so I am using the inline toolbar giving to it a div that I can control. The problem is that when the editor is not focused the bar auto hides, and I don't want this behavior.

I used a trick that it worked decently until now:

```
editor.on("blur", function() { return false; });
```

The problem is that now I will have multiple editors on the page and when I focus one the other lose the focus so the toolbar disappears.

How can I solve this?

Here is an example with 2 editors:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/PDdaab/4

With one it works (does not hide the toolbar):

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/PDdaab/5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works, taking advantage of mutation observers:

In the config:

```
      init_instance_callback: editor => {
        // listen for toolbar element mutation
        const wantedValue =
          "border-width: 1px; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 440px; height: 30px;";
        let tbMutationObs = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
          mutations.forEach(function(m) {
            if (
              m.type === "attributes" &&
              m.attributeName === "style" &&
              m.oldValue === wantedValue
            ) {
              // toolbar has been hidden
              // remove display none to show it again
              m.target.style.display = "block";
            }
          });
        });

        // get the toolbar element, in my case, having multiple editor I scope them with toolbarId variable that I have in the global scope
        let s = `#${toolbarId} .mce-tinymce.mce-tinymce-inline.mce-container.mce-panel`;
        tbMutationObs.observe(document.querySelector(s), {
          attributes: true,
          attributeOldValue: true
        });

        editor.on("Remove", () => tbMutationObs.disconnect());
      },
```

Basically we listen when the element is hidden and instantly reset the display property to `block`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is how Inline mode is designed to work - only one editor has focus at one time so there is only one "instance" of TinyMCE ever invoked.  There is no way to have Inline while the toolbar stays for all instances - if you want that just go with the standard mode for TinyMCE.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is what I feared. There is a way to use the standard mode and anchor the sidebar at the bottom of the editor?

Comment: TinyMCE does not have a configuration option to put the toolbar at the bottom of the editor.  If you search Stack you will find various ways people have done so via CSS or JavaScript.  TinyMCE does have a way to affix the toolbar to a specific DOM element so if you have one under each editor you could use that configuration option:  https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#fixed_toolbar_container

Comment: the option you suggested is what I am doing.. you require to use inline mode to take advantage of that function so the main problem of the question remain...